# Replace all occurrences of the same key of an array with a character, skip the first replacement

Tags: python, regex, text

I tried many methods to solve this problem, but cannot do it in a few lines of code because I am new to Python. I was wondering if anyone has an elegant solution to the following problem.

I have original lines like this:

```
A: D

A: E

A: C

G: H
F: I

F: J

B: A

B: K

B: L

D: M

D: N

D: O

E: P

E: Q

C: R

C: S

C: T
```

How do I use Python to turn them into this form?

```
A: D; E; C

G: H

F: I; J

B: A; G; L

D: M; N; O

E: P; Q

C: R; S; T
```

In other words, combine entries that have the same characters before ":" and separate each elements with "; "

Comment: Have you tried to achieve this in Python already and if so what are you struggling with? Please remember that SO is _not_ a code writing service. Also you might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to edit your post so that it is more manageable for answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store in dictionary, then print:

```
lines = """foo: bar
foo: baz
a: b"""

result = {}
for line in lines.split("\n"):
    (word, sentence) = line.split(":",1)
    word = word.strip()
    if word not in result:
        result[word] = []
    result[word].append(sentence.strip())

for word in result.keys():
    print word + ": " + "; ".join(result[word])
```

Answer (score 0):

use a dictionary and split each line on ':'.

Read each line, Key is the pre `':'` split, value is the post `':'` split. Add some logic for first value vs appending values

```
my_dict = dict()

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key,value = line.split(':')
        if my_dict[key] is None:
            my_dict[key] = value
        else:
            my_dict[key] += '; {0}'.format(value)
```